# Does N++ have some include template plugin?

Tags: templates, notepad++

I am using N++ text editor. I was wondering is there some plugin that will allow text template creating? I need something similar to PHP:

```
lorem ipsum blablabla
include(my_template);
lorem ipsum blablabla
```

Or even better some themplating with $variables and heredoc:

```
require_heredoc(mytemplate);
lorem ipsum blablabla
$chapter1;
lorem ipsum blablabla
$chapter2;
lorem ipsum blablabla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for N++, you might have a look at **SnippetPlus** or **Snippets** plugins.

Also you might consider the [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com), it will give you templating capability system-wide.

Example:

```
::.lipsum::Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque etc etc.
```

Now, if you type .lipsum in any application, it gets deleted and replaced by long text. (Period at beggining of **.lipsum** is only my way of prefixing to avoid replacement if I want to type lipsum without triggering replacement.)

You can make it work also with variables, but then your macro would be slightly more difficult - you might want to display input box for every variable etc. You can also create macro **template(filename)** which will paste content of given filename in your templates folder.

For more details on AutoHotKey setup, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220666/in-notepad-change-tab-size-instantly/22880354#22880354).